# Есть ли способ отдавать страницу только для вставки в iframe?

Tags: php, apache, http, nginx

Собственно вопрос в заголовке.
Задача: отдать страницу только если её включают через iframe.
Может какие то HTTP заголовки или другие трюки?

Comment: Посмотрите какой у нее будет referer. но его и подделать можно при желании ...

Comment: @Mike именно этим вариант и не нравится :) Возможно есть более надежные решения.

Comment: Ну подделать все передаваемое по сети можно. для защиты вижу только загрузку в 2 стадии. на первой отдается некий JS код, сам код желательно что бы был достаточно сложно устроен и каждый раз был разным. его единственная цель - убедится что window!=window.top (мы в iframe) и сгенерить только в этом случае некий код по которому загрузится основная часть. и основная часть с одним и тем же кодом дважды не грузится. вопрос обхода - выполнить js-код с подмененным условием проверки, получить код до отправки серверу и задействование его без iframe

Comment: @Mike оформите как ответ, в случае если вариант лучше не будет найден, вы первый кандидат. Спасибо